# Usar metodos del formulario A desde el fomulario B( es instanciado por el formulario A) en C#

Tags: c#

tengo un problema en el desarrollo de una aplicación.

Mi problemática es la siguiente: tengo un formulario principal `A` en el que listo una serie de registros, pero editar un registro pulso sobre el `gridView` y aparece otro formulario `B` en el `load` del formulario `B` debo de ejecutar una función del formulario `A`. He intentado con el patrón singleton, con inyección dependencias pero no he logrado ejecutar la función del formulario `A`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stack, te recomiendo primero que leas (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , segundo las preguntas sin codigo no son bien recibidas por la comunidad, deberías de agregar el cogido que has intentado hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No es mas facil poner la función que ocupas en una clase, y esa clase ponerla publica para que puedas a acceder a ella desde los dos formularios, o tambien puedes hacer lo que puedes hacer en caso de que mandes datos, mardar los datos dependiendo de la fila en la que hagas clic

Comment: Empecemos por algo importante, ¿qué tecnología estas usando? Windows Forms? WPF? Asp?

Comment: declara la funcionde A que quieres ejecutar desde B como publica, y luego la ejecutas desde la instancia de B que hayas creado

Comment: hola la tecnología que uso es Windows Form. el detalle que tengo es que no puedo utilizar esa función en otra clase externa por que usa un componente de interfaz grafica en el formulario principal A. Debido a esto tengo que ejecutar la función uvicada en el formulario A desde el formulario B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he resulto de la siguiente forma.

1. Cree un interfaz `IMensaje` y dentro un método `void CerrarComonente();`
2. En el formulario `A` heredé esta interfaz `public partial class ListaPersonal : Form, IMensaje` y creé el método de la interfaz dentro `A` Y a su vez todo el código dentro del componente que deseaba usar dentro del método `public void CerrarComonente(){}`
3. En la formulario `B` cree la propiedad  `public IMensaje MensajeP { get; set; }` del tipo de mi interfaz.
4. Después dentro de `Load` de `B` realice la siguiente instancia al final de toda la carga de objetos `MensajeP.CerrarVentana();`

Comment: Creo que sobredimencionaste tu problema. Bastaba con un metodo publico en A, y un load con parametros en B y pasarle el A como parametro....

Comment: Jejeje Gracias por la repuesta, ya lo intente amigo pero me genera un error  el metodó publico  public void CerrarVentana(){
                              splashScreenManager1.CloseWaitForm();
                             }    el mensaje dice que no se pude ejecutar  splashScreenManager1.CloseWaitForm(); ya que no se encuentra abierto

Comment: Habria que ver que error te tiro eso.